# inline editing - no matching records

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to get the "insert" link, provided with inline editing, to show even when there are no matching items.  I am using Sharepoint Designer 2010, and I built a webpart page from the master page.  It has a DVWP and the "no-matching items template" doesn't show the insert item link.  I can probably use newform.aspx for the first record, but would prefer to keep everything uniform if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

"The easiest way is to go to the template that is rendered if the DVWP has items, and copy the insert link from that. Then paste it into the template that's rendered if there are no items found."

I answered your question over here already though... Check it out:
[Inline Editing No-Matching Records](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/STP/viewtopic.php?t=1699&p=6322#p6322)